# Finding the kernel of $\phi:\Bbb{Z}_6\to\Bbb{Z}_2 $ given by $\phi(x)=$ the remainder of $x$ when divided by $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi:\Bbb{Z}_6\to\Bbb{Z}_2 $ be given by $\phi(x)=$ the remainder of $x$ when divided by $2$.

I have become fairly confident with calculating the left and right cosets, but what is the kernel for the above function?

Comment: i do not understand why did you mentioned about cosets.. That is not relevant here.. In any case what is your definition of kernel?

Comment: maybe by kernel you mean $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_6 \colon \phi(x) = 0\} = \{0,2,4\}$

Answer (score 1):

Given groups $G$ and $H$, and a group homomorphism $\phi : G \to H$, the kernel of $\phi$ is $\ker\phi = \{g \in G \mid \phi(g) = e_H\}$ where $e_H$ denotes the identity element of $H$.

Here $G = \mathbb{Z}_6$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}_2$ so $e_H = 0$. Therefore $\ker\phi = \{g \in \mathbb{Z}_6 \mid \phi(g) = 0\}$. Which of the numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ have remainder $0$ when divided by $2$?

Comment: 2 has remainder 0

Comment: Actually 0,2, and 4

Comment: Good. So the kernel of $\phi$ is $\{0, 2, 4\}$.